# Set operation problem related to probability measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory

In a probability problem. I think I need to solve the following question.

How to use the following properties.

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}[A_n] = 0$.

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{m=n}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}[A_m \setminus A_{m+1}] = 0$.

To prove this:
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}[\bigcup\limits_{m=n}^{\infty} A_m] \to 0$.

Intuitively, it holds, but I need to figure out what is exactly the realtion between $\bigcup\limits_{m=n}^{\infty} A_m$ and $\bigcup\limits_{m=n}^{\infty} (A_m \setminus A_{m+1})$ and finally give a complete proof.

Comment: Can you check the subscripts of $A$ at different places if they should be $m$ or $n$

Comment: @KB, thank you , fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A_m \cup A_{m+1} = (A_m \setminus A_{m+1}) \cup A_{m+1} $

Applying this iteratively, 
$\bigcup\limits_{m=n}^{k>n} A_m = \bigcup\limits_{m=n}^{k-1} (A_m \setminus A_{m+1}) \cup A_{k}  $

Therefore, $ \mathbb{P} \left[\bigcup\limits_{m=n}^{k>n} A_m \right] = 
 \mathbb{P} \left[ \bigcup\limits_{m=n}^{k-1} (A_m \setminus A_{m+1}) \cup A_{k}  \right]$

$\mathbb{P} \left[ \bigcup\limits_{m=n}^{k-1} (A_m \setminus A_{m+1}) \cup A_{k}  \right]
\leq \displaystyle \sum_{m=n}^{k-1} \mathbb{P} \left[ A_m \setminus A_{m+1} \right] + \mathbb{P}[A_k] $

$ \therefore \mathbb{P} \left[\bigcup\limits_{m=n}^{k>n} A_m \right] 
\leq 
\displaystyle \sum_{m=n}^{k-1} \mathbb{P} \left[ A_m \setminus A_{m+1} \right] + \mathbb{P}[A_k] 
 $

First take the limit $k \to \infty$, which allows you to take the limit inside the $\mathbb{P}$ on the LHS and removes the $\mathbb{P}[A_k]$ on the RHS. Then take $n \to \infty$ and you get your answer.

Comment: @NickPeterson The question states that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{m=n}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}[A_m \setminus A_{m+1}] = 0$

Comment: That's incorrect, let $A_m =  [0,1]$ for all $m$, then you can see $\cup A_m \neq \cup (A_m \setminus A_{m+1}) = \emptyset$.

Comment: @Beginner Right! Can you check now?

Comment: "On the RHS of the inequality, all sets are disjoint." This is incorrect. Also, "inequality should be "equation". But your idea inspired me. I figured it out and I will post it in my post now

Comment: @Beginner  Alright. Could you give the counter-example (just like above)?

Comment: $A_1 \setminus A_2$ and $A_3 \setminus A_4$ might not be disjoint. I mean you should be sure this collection  is mutually disjoint.

Comment: Oh right! In that case it'll be an inequality.